# How to access component form data in a Redux `matchDispatchToProps` function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

Edited.  People have suggested passing in values to my action creator but I've tried that every way I can think of and it fails to work.

I'm currently getting my first taste of Redux and trying to get my call to `mapDispatchToProps` to read information in a form on button click but I'm not clear as how to get it to do so.  The form component is rendered by React, and so it's a question of being able to bind when it's available but Redux is a monkey wrench I don't know how to compensate for yet.  Essentially I have this for my component:

```
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { action } from '../actions/actionFile';

const Add = (props) => (
    <div className="add">
      <input className="field-one" type="text" placeholder="One" />
      <input className="field-two" type="number" placeholder="Two" />
      <input className="field-three" type="number" placeholder="Three" />
      <button onClick={() => props.addItem('Literally anything')}>+</button>
    </div>
)

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return {
    action: () => dispatch(action({ 
      // I have three fields I need to update in the store.
    }))
  }
}

export default connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(Add);
```

And this for my actions file:

```
import { ADD_ITEM } from '../constants/items';

export const addItem = (val) => {
    return {
        type: ADD_ITEM,
        val
    }
}
```

But if I run this and set a breakpoint inside the action creator the `val` value is undefined.  For some reason Redux isn't letting me feed dynamic data to the action creator and I don't understand why.

Obviously I can't just pull the information with `querySelector` because the form doesn't exist when the callback is loaded.  If I fill the object passed to the action with hard-coded dummy values it works, but I'm not able to pull in data from the form fields.  I'm not even clear as to where to start with this.  Any direction is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can't access any data from Redux state, or from *inside* the component, in `mapDispatch`, because it is used as part of a wrapper component that goes around your actual component (and thus doesn't have access to anything in your component's state).

Your main options are:

- Pass any necessary values as arguments into the function, like `props.action(a, b, c)`
- Switch to using the React-Redux hooks API (`useSelector` and `useDispatch`), which lets you access data from the Redux store *inside* of your function component.  You can then capture these values while defining a click handler.

Also, as a side note: if you are going to use `connect`, you should use [the "object shorthand" form of `mapDispatch`](https://react-redux.js.org/using-react-redux/connect-mapdispatch#defining-mapdispatchtoprops-as-an-object) rather than defining it as a function.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add onChange event handler to your three fields and store data of each input into your component state.
Then on button click dispatch action using this.props.action with data in your state.
In this way you can get all of your data into redux.

```
render() { 
 return <button onClick={() =>this.props.toggleTodo(this.props.todoId)} />
} 

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => { 
    return { toggleTodo: todoId =>dispatch(toggleTodo(todoId)) } 
}
```

For reference -[Connect: Dispatching Actions with mapDispatchToProps · React Redux](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://react-redux.js.org/using-react-redux/connect-mapdispatch%23:%7E:text%3DAs%2520the%2520second%2520argument%2520passed,dispatch%2520to%2520dispatch%2520an%2520action.%26text%3DWith%2520React%2520Redux%252C%2520your%2520components,connect%2520does%2520it%2520for%2520you.&ved=2ahUKEwiqhIzGhJbqAhWacn0KHXvzB0sQFjACegQIDhAM&usg=AOvVaw1-ONblmFAUwWyoQBbwlFGO&cshid=1592850843131)